# Could one web page have multiple html elements?

Tags: html, xhtml

Say

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>code here</div>
        <html><head>...</head><body>...</body></html>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tested it in Firefox and it works. Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this right?

No, it is invalid. Firefox is just being lenient and making the best out of what is a broken structure.

If in doubt, run it through the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/check):

> Line 6, Column 14: document type does not allow element "html" here